# how many connections can handle a Java app simultaneously on a tomcat server. Difference between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, concurrency, process

I'm trying to understand the difference between threads. I read that one core can run only one thread simultaneously. But. For instance, Tomcat can serve 200 connections at the same time on one core CPU, using its thread pool (correct me if I'm wrong). Meantime Java app provides one thread per request to the server. So I'm just trying to make it clear for myself how it works. I understand that this question looks like nubby, but it is better to ask.

I understand that there's a concurrency factor. But does it explain everything?
Thanks.

Comment: The OS switches between the threads. A core is not locked to run one thread, even though it is limited to run one thread only at a specific time.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer so the case is just in the concurrency... Thanks.